# Django accessing a JSONResponse from another views file

Tags: python, json, django, api

I have two files within views directory, /views/api.py and /views/pages.py

/views/api.py has methods which return JSONResponses objects

Example:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def foos(request):
    foos = get_list_or_404(Foo)
    data = [{'id': foo.id,
            'name': foo.name,
            'description': foo.description,
            'tag': foo.tag} for foo in foos]
    return JsonResponse({'foos': data})
```

/views/pages.py will have methods that will access some of the methods from /views/api.py and add them to context and render a page.

Example:

```
def home(request):
    foos = api.foos(request)
    print foos
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

On the line print stacks, I can see the JSONResponse object with the correct data. How do I access individual values within foos so I can create a list or a dictionary or something that is custom for each view?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You shouldn't be calling views directly from other views. If you need to access the same data in your home view as in your api view, you should create a utility function that returns a dict that can be called from both places.

Comment: @DanielRoseman would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First factor out the common part (nb : rewritten using `Queryset.values()` for efficiency):

```
# somewhere.py
def get_foos():
    return list(Foo.objects.values('id', 'name', 'description', 'tag'))
```

Then call this from your views:

```
# views/api.py
from somewhere import get_foos

@api_view(['GET'])
def foos(request):
    data = get_foos()
    return JsonResponse({'foos': data})
```

and

```
# views/pages.py   
from somewhere import get_foos

def home(request):
    foos = get_foos()
    print foos
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```